# How to disable anonymous access on LDAP

Tags: security, debian, ldap, openldap

I need to secure my LDAP server and am not quite sure the best way to go about it. I am running Debian "Lenny", and using OpenLDAP (slapd).

I notice that if I run:

`ldapsearch -x -W -b 'dc=example,dc=com' -H 'ldap://127.0.0.1:389/' 'objectclass=*'`

and just press ENTER when it prompts for a password, that I get a list of directory entries. Anonymous access is not acceptable if I am opening this up to the internet, but cannot find a way to disable anonymous access.

I have tried modifying `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` to the following:

```
access to *
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by * none
```

... but that doesn't do the trick.

After this, I will get it running over TLS, but it is pointless doing that step while still allowing anonymous access.

Any ideas?

Comment: TLS is not completely pointless. It also allows securing passwords for non-anonymous binds, and making sure it's really your LDAP server you're connecting to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To completely disable anonymous bind, add this line to slapd.conf:

```
disallow bind_anon
```

and restart the slapd service.

Comment: For FreeBSD:  This line "disallow bind_anon"  should be added in the global section. Adding at the bottom did not work for me.
https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=slapd.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.3-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html

Comment: AS @sunil_rbc mentioned, works on FreeBSD as long as you add this config in the global section of slapd.conf

Answer (score 22):

If the accepted answer does not work for you (it didn't for me on Ubuntu), try the following.

Create ldiff file:

```
nano /usr/share/slapd/ldap_disable_bind_anon.ldif
```

Paste in this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDisallows
olcDisallows: bind_anon

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
```

And then run:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /usr/share/slapd/ldap_disable_bind_anon.ldif
```

Comment: works on ubuntu!!

Comment: Are the 1st and 3rd ones actually required?

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, slapd, 2.4.49 I only had to deploy the 1st modification of the 3

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to go SSL/TLS soon, you may want to consider using **client certificate verification** to further tighten your security. Stunnel with `-v -A` options would do nicely.